# "Missing artifact" errors in pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>cassandra</name>
   <description>cassandra connector</description>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Error is shown at **line 12**.
I have copied and pasted the maven dependency from here.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.5

Comment: Missing artifact: _*which*_ artifact?

Comment: Which line is line 12?

Comment: I just pasted this dependency into my project and Maven was able to find it.  I think your Maven cannot connect to the central repository.

Comment: Are you connecting through a Maven repository like Nexus?

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Have you tried forcing Maven to do a clean?  Did you check your `.m2` folder to see if the Cassandra JAR is there?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get rid of this error is by downloading bundle file on your local machine from below URL & try below mvn:install command to update it on your local repository.

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.5/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar

mvn install:install-file -Dfile="cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar" -DgroupId=com.datastax.cassandra -DartifactId=cassandra-driver-core -Dversion=2.1.5 -Dpackaging=jar

Or other way, if you are connecting to Maven repository like Nexus & having rights to update your repository then you can deploy your bundle to Nexus using below mvn:deploy command.

mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://<>:<>/nexus/content/groups/public -DrepositoryId=nexuspublic -Dfile="cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar" -DgroupId=com.datastax.cassandra -DartifactId=cassandra-driver-core -Dversion=2.1.5 -Dpackaging=jar

Answer (score 0):

In my case I figured out two issues causing this problem, firstly older versions usually throws such errors, so make sure to use the latest version of the dependency. Secondly, using nexus instead of maven repository fixed my issue and it does not say "missing artifact" anymore, I figured this out when I saw a note in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pentaho-kettle/kettle-engine/9.3.0.0-115
indicating that the artifact is actually in nexus repository. Lastly, try to be consistent with your versions, for instance, if your using multiple dependencies for the same bundle, stick with the same version as they are most compatible with each other I believe (preferably latest version).